# "No libraries found for 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions'"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Our professor hasn't explained to us yet how dependencies work or what they are at all, so I'm at a loss on how to solve this. I opened a project from him on Intellij but I'm having trouble getting the preconditions to work. I still don't quite understand what Gradle and Maven are and what they do.

`java: package com.google.common.base does not exist`

When I tried to download the Jar from the web, it couldn't be found. `No libraries found for 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions'`.

I tried to download it myself, but I don't know how I'm supposed to add the Jar file to Intellij or to the project.

Comment: Is this a maven or gradle project? Please show the build.gradle or pom.xml file.

Comment: @DariuszUrbanek It's a gradle project (altough like I said I just opened the project file, I don't know if I'm supposed to change anything on Intellij). And how can I access either of those files?

Comment: if you cannot access the files I cannot help. Basically, this dependency has to be in the build.gradle file under the `dependencies`. and Gradle should download this for you.